# what is this bullet point <li> not showing up with circles?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to show some bullet point list circles on my webpage, but it doesn't seem to show, and I tried using firebug but I can't find what's wrong, I went through my whole css file, and I don't see where the problem is, i want the list to be vertical with circles!

Please can you help me, here is the code :

```css
/* Browser resets. */
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, code,
del, dfn, em, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, dialog, figure, footer, header,
hgroup, nav, section {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}



#fancy_ajax .note{    cursor:default; }

/* Three styles for the notes: */

.yellow{
    background-color:#FDFB8C;
    border:1px solid #DEDC65;
}

.blue{
    background-color:#A6E3FC;
    border:1px solid #75C5E7;
}

.green{
    background-color:#A5F88B;
    border:1px solid #98E775;
}

/* Each note has a data span, which holds its ID */
span.data{    display:none; }



/* Green button class: */
a.green-button,a.green-button:visited{
    color:black;
    display:block;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    height:15px;
    padding:6px 5px 4px;
    text-align:center;
    width:60px;

    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #DDDDDD;
    background:url(../img/button_green.png) no-repeat left top;
}

a.green-button:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    background-position:left bottom;
}

.author{
    /* The author name on the note: */
    bottom:10px;
    color:#666666;
    font-family:Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
}

#main{
    /* Contains all the notes and limits their movement: */
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    width:980px;
    height:500px;
    z-index:10;
    background:url(img/add_a_note_help.gif) no-repeat left top;
}

h3.popupTitle{
    border-bottom:1px solid #DDDDDD;
    color:#666666;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:0 0 5px;
}

#noteData{
    /* The input form in the pop-up: */
    height:200px;
    margin:0px 0 0 0px;
    width:350px;
}

.note-form label{
    display:block;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}

.note-form textarea, .note-form input[type=text]{
    background-color:#FCFCFC;
    border:1px solid #AAAAAA;
    font-family:Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size:19px;
        font-weight: bold;
    height:60px;
    padding:5px;
    width:300px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

.note-form input[type=text]{    height:auto; }

.color{
    /* The color swatches in the form: */
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
    height:10px;
    margin:0 5px 0 0;
    width:10px;
}

#note-submit{    margin:20px auto; }


body {
    height:100%;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* custom selection colors */
::-moz-selection {
    color: #fff;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.85);
    background: #ea4c88;
}

::selection {
    color: #fff;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.85);
    background: #ea4c88;
}

/* Links */
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  #19558D;
    font-size: inherit;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: #336699;
}

a img {
    border: none;
}

/* Input fields + label */
input, textarea {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    padding: 5px;
}

label {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0pxpx;
    width: 120px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#error {
    font-size: 14px;
}

/* Lists */
li {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    list-style-type: circle;
    display:inline;
}

li a {
    margin-left: inherit;
}

#like_text {
    float: left;
    color: #0099CC;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: inherit;
}

.like_list_element {
    width: 681px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    height: 35px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
}

.like_list_element:hover {
    width: 681px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    height: 35px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
}


.micro_avatar {
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #D1D1D1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #D1D1D1;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #D1D1D1;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

/* "Super" headline */
h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #666666;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times new roman", serif;
}

/* "Medium (bold)" headline */
h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* Normal headline (used on profile page) */
.normal_headline {
    font-size: 22px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* "Standard" headline */
h3 {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* page structure */

/* Container - main content goes here */
#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    height:100%;
    width: 897px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Left (main) content */
#left_content {
    float: left;
    width: 485px;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-left: -15px;
}

ul.statuses{
    margin:10px 0;
}

ul.statuses li {
    position:relative;
    padding:15px 15px 15px 10px;
    list-style:none;
    font-size:12px;
}





div.tweetTxt{

    float:left;
    width:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

ul.statuses a img.avatar{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    border:1px solid #446600;
}
div.date{
    line-height:18px;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#999999;

}



.question_link{

 float:left;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left:40px;
   color:blue;




}

#answerText {

    float:left;
width:480px;
margin-left:40px;
margin-bottom: 5px;

}
#answerText ul{

    margin-left:40px;
}
#answerText li {

    list-style-type: circle;
    font-size:30px;


}
.answerActions {

    float:left;
    margin-left:40px;
    font-size:9px;


}
.thanks{
    font-weight:bold;
}
.content{
    float:left;


}
/* Used for seperating content eg. Timeline && photos */
.left_content_seperator {
    width: 485px;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    height: auto;
}

/* Used in eg. postphoto.php */
.big_content_seperator {
    width: 897px;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/* Right side content */
.right_content {
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 14px;
        margin-right:80px;
}

/* Used for seperating content eg. Timeline && photos */
.right_content_seperator {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 33px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.right_content_seperator_home {
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

/* For footer + header (outside the main container) */
.small_container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;

}

/* The bar on the top of the page */
.top_bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
}
#search {

 width: 502px;
 padding: 10px;
 height:20px;
 margin: 10px 0px 0px -30px;
 background-color:#505759;
 float:left
}

.question_box{

background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #CCCCCC #999999 #999999 #CCCCCC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: #000000;
    font: 16px arial,sans-serif;
    margin: -5px 0px 0px -5px;
    padding: 5px 8px 0px 6px;
    width:380px;
    height:25px

}
input.blur {
                color: #999;
            }
#search a {
    color: #E5E5E5;
    text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
}

#search a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;

}
/* Logotype container */
.logotype {
    background-color:#671E1E;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
        color:white;
        padding:10px;

        margin: 10px 30px 0px 0px;
}

/* The menu on the top of the page */
.top_menu {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;


}

.top_menu a {
    color: #E5E5E5;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.top_menu a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: inherit;
}

/* Main content + form container on the front page */
.text_box {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 590px;
}

/* Box for the iPhone image on the front page */
.iphone_promo {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 590px;
}

/* Red arrow next to the iPhone picture */
.arrow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 210px;
    margin-bottom: -145px;
}

/* Typography */
.small_copy {
    font-size: 12px;
}

#menu_list ul{




}
#menu_list li{


}

    .not_selected {

         -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-image: url("http://d1vgw4v7ja2ido.cloudfront.net/-9dfe92083011731d.gif");
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 10px;


    color: #444444;
    cursor: default;



}
.not_selected:hover{

    background-color:lightblue;
}




.selected{


      -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-image: url("http://d1vgw4v7ja2ido.cloudfront.net/-9dfe92083011731d.gif");
    background-position: left center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 10px;

    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    color: #444444;
    cursor: default;

}

#menu_list li{
    margin-left: inherit;
}

.right_seperator {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #999999;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: auto;
}

.light_gray_serif {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times new roman", serif;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 14px;
}

/* Forms */
#email_form {
    width: 285px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    outline: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #999999;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    float: left;
}

#submit_button {
    width: 295px;
    height: 52px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: -1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #F9AA33;
    float: right;
}

#username_form {
    width: 448px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    outline: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    float: right;
}

#password_form {
    width: 448px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    outline: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    float: right;
}

.standard_big_form {
    width: 448px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    outline: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    float: right;
}

/* Big login button */
#login_button {
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    height: 52px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: -1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #F9AA33;
    float: right;
}

#login_button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

/* Standard buttons */
.big_button {
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    height: 52px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #F9AA33;
    float: right;
}

.big_button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}

.profile_name_container {
    width: auto;
}

.follow_container {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.follow_button {
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: justify;
    color: #0099CC;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: url(../images/follow-icon.png) no-repeat 4px 6px;
}

.follow_button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    background-image: url(../images/follow-icon.png) no-repeat 4px 6px;
}

.unfollow_button {
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: justify;
    color: #0099CC;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: url(../images/unfollow-icon.png) no-repeat 4px 6px;
}

.unfollow_button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    background-image: url(../images/unfollow-icon.png) no-repeat 4px 6px;
}

.push_footer {
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}

/* Footer (container) of the page */
.footer {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  width: 897px;
    height: 49px;
    border-top: 1px solid #999999;
}

/* "Photoblogging through events." text. */
.footer_info {
    font-size: 14px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

/* The link to 'Support & Feature requests' */
.footer_link {
    font-size: 14px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

/*** Colors ***/

/* Blue gradient (css gradients, #336699 is used for IE and older browsers) */
.blue_gradient {
    background: #336699;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0099CC), to(#336699));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0099CC,  #336699);
}

/* Yellow gradient (for button) #FBAA33 = orange */
.yellow_gradient {
    background: #FBAA33;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FBF16E), to(#FBAA33));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FBF16E,  #FBAA33);

}

.yellow_gradient:hover {
    background: #F6D05A;
}


/* Image design */
.photo {
    float: left;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #D1D1D1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #D1D1D1;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #D1D1D1;
}

.photo_thumbnail:hover {
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    -moz-opacity:0.6;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.6;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.big_photo_container {
    text-align: center;
    width: 666px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.event_name {
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 169px;
    float: left;
}

.trash_can {
    height: 17px;
    width: 14px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    float: right;
}

.trash_can:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: -1px;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
}

/* Image design */
.big_photo {
    margin-top: 15px;
    max-width: 656px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #D1D1D1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #D1D1D1;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #D1D1D1;
}

.profile_photo {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #D1D1D1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #D1D1D1;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #D1D1D1;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.profile {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

/* Heart sign */
.fav {
    margin-left: 0px;
    color: #0099CC;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: url(../images/heart-icons.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
}

.fav:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    background: url(../images/heart-icons.png) no-repeat 4px -13px #EDEDED;
}

.highlight {
    margin-left: 0px;
    color: #0099CC;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: url(../images/heart-icons.png) no-repeat 4px -13px;
}

.highlight:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    background: url(../images/heart-icons.png) no-repeat 4px 4px #EDEDED;
}

/* Heart sign */
.likes {
    font-size: inherit;
}

/* Views */
.views {
    padding-left: 20px;
    float: right;
}

/* Costum */

/* Removes underlines for eg. buttons */
.no_underline:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Margins */
.small_margin_top {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.negative_margin_top {
    margin-top: -4px;
}

.custom_margin_top {
    margin-top: 48px;
}

.no_margin_left {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.no_margin_top {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

/* Paddings */
.no_padding_top {
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.normal_font_weight {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.photo_label {
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 6px;
    text-align: left;
}




/* button basics */
  a.minibutton {
    display:inline-block;
    height:23px;
    padding:0 0 0 3px;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#333;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #fff;
    background:url(http://github.com/images/modules/buttons/minibutton_matrix.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin-right:4px;
    border:none;
    overflow:visible;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  a.minibutton>span {
    display:block;
    height:23px;
    padding:0 10px 0 8px;
    line-height:23px;
    background:url(http://github.com/images/modules/buttons/minibutton_matrix.png) 100% 0 no-repeat;
  }

  a.minibutton:hover, a.minibutton:focus {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:-1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-position:0 -30px;
  }
  a.minibutton:hover>span, a.minibutton:focus>span {background-position:100% -30px;}

  a.minibutton.mousedown{background-position:0 -60px; }
  a.minibutton.mousedown>span{background-position:100% -60px; }

/* answer button */
  a.answer {
    display:inline-block;
    height:23px;
    padding:0 0 0 3px;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#333;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #fff;
    background:url(http://github.com/images/modules/buttons/minibutton_matrix.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin-right:4px;
    border:none;
    overflow:visible;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  a.answer>span {
    display:block;
    height:23px;
    padding:0 10px 0 8px;
    line-height:23px;
    background:url(http://github.com/images/modules/buttons/minibutton_matrix.png) 100% 0 no-repeat;
  }

  a.answer:hover, a.answer:focus {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:-1px -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-position:0 -30px;
  }
  a.answer:hover>span, a.answer:focus>span {background-position:100% -30px;}

  a.answer.mousedown{background-position:0 -60px; }
  a.answer.mousedown>span{background-position:100% -60px; }

/* with icon */
  a.btn-download .icon {
    float:left;
    margin-left:-4px;
    width:18px;
    height:22px;
    background:url(http://github.com/images/modules/buttons/minibutton_icons.png?v20100306) 0 0 no-repeat;
  }
  a.btn-download .icon {background-position:-20px 0;}
  a.btn-download:hover .icon, a.btn-download:focus .icon {background-position:-20px -25px;}

  #profile_pic{

     padding:5px;
    border:1px #AAAAAA solid;
      float:left;
}

ul.stats{

    width:auto;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  
   
}

ul.stats li{

    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;

}
.stats_number{

    font-weight:bold;
   
font-size:10px;
}
 .stats_text{

    font-size:9px;
    color:#505759;
}

ul.followingBar{

    width:auto;
    float:left;

    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

}
.watchingTopics{

    float:left
}

ul.followingBar li{

    display:block;
   margin: 10px 0 0 0 ;
    border-bottom:1px #999999 solid;

}

.topicFollow{
    padding-bottom:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
}
.related_questions{
    padding-bottom:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.panel
    {
    margin-left:50px; margin-right:50px; margin-bottom:5px; background-color:#D3E7F5;  padding:6px; width:400px;
    display:none; float:left;
    }
    .load_comment
    {
    margin-left:50px; margin-right:50px; margin-bottom:5px; background-color:#D3E7F5; height:auto; padding:6px; width:400px; font-size:12px;
        float:left;
    }
    .flash_load
    {
    margin-left:50px; margin-right:50px; margin-bottom:5px;height:20px; padding:6px; width:400px;
    display:none;    }
        .loadplace{
            margin-top:70px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="statuses">

<li>
<div id="answerText">
    <ul>
        <li>google</li>
        <li>yahoo</li>
        <li>quora</li>
        
    </ul>
    </div>
</li> 

</ul>
```

Comment: Ensuring some `padding-left` on the `ul`, solved this for me. `ul { padding-left: 40px; }`

Answer (score 110, accepted):

`li` only gets its `list-style`-related  styles applied if it has `display: list-item`

Answer (score 35):

Your style for `<li>` is wrong:

```
li {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    list-style-type: circle;
    display: inline;
 }
```

should be

```
li {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    list-style-type: circle;
 }
```

Comment: @pingpong: so put a class on your top menu, and add `display:inline` to it.

Comment: Another setting to play with inside UL is:
`list-style-position: inside;`

Answer (score 13):

Try ensuring there are no:

**list-style-type: none;**

in your css file.

Answer (score 5):

I found that having `overflow-x: hidden;` (which I had applied to `*`) was hiding my bullets.

Answer (score 2):

You attributed `display:inline;` to the LI tag, which explains why they're showing up horizontally instead of vertical.  Get rid of that attribute.

Comment: but then that ruins my menu at the top but fixes my list :)) whats the solution

Answer (score 1):

My issue was caused by:

```
::marker { 
    content: none;
}
```

I was able to resolve by updating the CSS for my element to include:

```
li::marker {
    content: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

list not display bullet points

list-style-type:none;
Hey , you may have a problem in selector for example we have this code for list

some text

soke text

so our css code become like this

#ls{ list-style-type: circle;}
select with id value if you have multiple list .

Comment: I was try it @ᴢʜᴀʀᴀ-ᴄᴏᴅᴇ-ᴋɪʟʟᴇʀ can u tell other way

Comment: list not display bullet points

list-style-type:none;
Hey , you may have a problem in selector for example we have this code for list

<ol id='ls'>
<li>some text</li>
<li>soke text</li>
</ol>
so our css code become like this

#ls{ list-style-type: circle;}
select with id value if you have multiple list .

Comment: Can u try this way